# WebRequest.Create(uri) with a local html file

Tags: .net, cookies, webbrowser-control, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have an application that uses an WebBrowser. This webBrowser load local pages (file://PathOfPage.html).

I want to be able to do a request to this page because of I need to get/set cookies in that page.

The problem is that if i use like uri something like this "file://Program Files/..../page.html", WebRequest.Create(uri) give me an UnSupportedException because of that uri.

My code:

```
Uri uri = webBrowser1.Url;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string cookie = response.Headers.Get("Cookie");
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your Uri format (file:///), also helps to specify if its relative or absolute (you well get an exception for that too)
Here is some example:
var uri = new Uri("file://C/thing/otherthing/whatever.html", UriKind.Absolute);

Hope this help!
Tom